# encoding in zlib and insert into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a user's input, in utf8, very long.
I would like to put it in mysql, by zipping it.
So :

```
value =  value.decode('utf8', 'replace') 
value =  value.encode('zlib') 
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO data (data_id, value) VALUES (%s,%s)''', (data_id, value  , ))
```

Whatever i do (value = str(value), value = value.decode... ), it doesn't work..

Examples of error code :

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 8177: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 747: ordinal not in range(128)'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 2478: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to change field's structure : longtext, longbinary, blob,...
Nothing.

An answer ?

Comment: You need to escape and quote the substitution, not simply use %s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `value.encode('zlib')` will be binary, which is not necessarily valid UTF-8 (ie. almost never).

I would do this:

```
value = value.encode('zlib').encode('base64')
```

This will give you a long ASCII string, which can be safely included in your SQL query.